# Error when trying to sign a .apk file

Tags: android, apk, signing, jarsigner

I am having a problem with signing my unsigned .apk file.

When ever I try to enter this command `jarsigner –verbose –sigalg MD5withRSA –digestalg SHA1 –keystore my-release-key.keystore AmazonInAppSample-release-unsigned.apk alias_name`

I get this error:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: /Users/user7259/.keystore (No such file or directory)
```

I executed this command with my current directory being the bin folder where my keystore and .apk file are found.

I also made sure I entered the correct password.

If I try to enter a blank pass i get this message:

```
jarsigner: you must enter key password
```

If I try to enter a correct or invalid password, I get this message:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: /Users/user7259/.keystore (No such file or directory)
```

Update:
Do I need Java JDK 7 installed to use the –sigalg MD5withRSA –digestalg SHA1 ?

Comment: The jarsigner sstill looks like is looking the file from the root path. Also files with dot arent hidden on unixfilesystems?